# Write to file. (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I can't figure out how to write a Binary Search Tree to file recursively. I open a BufferWriter with the file to wrtie too, in the Tree class. I then send the BufferWriter to the Node class to traverse the tree inorder and write to file. But it doesn't work.

```
public void write(String filePath)
{
  if(root != null) {
    try {
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
      root.write(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}

public void write(BufferedWriter out)
{
    if (this.getLeft() != null) this.getLeft().write(out);
    out.write(this.data());
    if (this.getRight() != null) this.getRight().write(out);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work!" What are you expecting, what do you see happening?

Comment: Consider handling the `IOException`, even if just with a line to `System.err` or equivalent.  As unlikely as it is that you're getting an exception, if your code isn't working it would suck to be swallowing the exception silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look so bad! Could it be you're just missing the `close()` on your `BufferedWriter` when you're done? The file will likely not be written correctly if there's no `close`.